# Difference in the behaviour of BufferedReader.ready()

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, java-io

I am trying to simulate a simple HTTP server and a client using Sockets.
BufferedReader is used to read the request, line by line. 
For identifying the end of socket's input stream, BufferedReader's ready() method is used.

Java Doc for ready:

```
Returns:
     True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for 
      input, false otherwise. Note that returning false does not 
      guarantee that the next read will block.
```

This works fine when I hit the server from a Browser. But keeps on returning true when I tried it from a java application. Do I need to include anything in Java program for BufferedReader's ready to return false?

Server:

```
package com.test.http.server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class HttpWebServer {

    private static final String ROOT_URL = "/";
    private static final String FAV_ICON_URL = "/favicon.ico";
    private static final String GET_METHOD = "GET";
    private static final String POST_METHOD = "POST";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8081);

        System.out.println("Established connection........."
                + serverSocket.getLocalSocketAddress());

        Socket clientSocket = null;

        while (true) {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            new HttpWebServer().handleRequest(clientSocket);

        }


    }

    private void handleRequest(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Received a http request with data as follows");

        InputStream socketInputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socketInputStream));
        String line = null;
        String url = null;
        String method = null;
        StringBuilder isStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            isStringBuilder.append(line).append("\r\n");

            if (url == null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                method = line.split("\\ ")[0];
                url = line.split("\\ ")[1];
            }


            if (!br.ready())
                break;

        }

        System.out.println(isStringBuilder.toString());

        if (url != null && (method != null) && method.trim().equals(GET_METHOD)) {
            if (url.trim().equals(ROOT_URL))
                handleGetRootRequest(clientSocket);
            else if (url.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(FAV_ICON_URL))
                handleGetIconRequest(clientSocket);
        }

        /*
         * byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
         * 
         * int count = 0;
         * 
         * do{ count = socketInputStream.read(bytes); String output = new
         * String(bytes, 0, count); System.out.print(output);
         * System.out.flush();
         * 
         * //count = socketInputStream.read(bytes); System.out.println(count);
         * 
         * }while(socketInputStream.available() > 0);
         */
        System.out.println("Completed processing request");
    }



    private void handleGetIconRequest(Socket clientSocket) {
        System.out.println("Yet to implement !!");
    }



    private void handleGetRootRequest(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {

        OutputStream clientOS = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK ").append("\r\n").append("\r\n")
                .append("<TITLE>").append("SUCCESS").append("</TITLE>");

        String response = sb.toString();

        clientOS.write(response.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        clientOS.flush();
        clientOS.close();
        clientSocket.close();

    }

}
```

Client:

```
package com.test.http.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class HttpSimpleClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost",8081);

        StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        requestBuilder.append("GET")
        .append(" / ").append("HTTP/1.1").append("\r\n")
        .append("Connection: keep-alive").append("\r\n").append("\r\n")
        .append(" Some Body");

        OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socketOutputStream));

        bw.write(requestBuilder.toString());
        bw.flush();


        System.out.println("<Client> Send:"+ requestBuilder.toString());



        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            responseBuilder.append(line);

            if(!br.ready()){
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(" Response: "+requestBuilder.toString());

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

closing the bw after `bw.flush();`close the Socket itself there by erroring out while reading the inputstream.

Comment: You're trying to identify the end of an input stream using ready(), although the javadoc you quoted clearly shows that it's not what the method allows doing. Just don't use ready(). Read lines fro the reader until it returns null. That's how you detect the end.

Comment: while((line = br.readLine()) != null) is not working out. thats why i introduced ready(). Well i dint completely understood the java doc of ready(). But it worked on Browser request.

Comment: `ready()` returning true only means that the next call to `char read()` will not block; it is hardly ever useful, and the way you use it in your code is wrong and it will break (as demonstrated by your own test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read to the end of request headers.  That is `"\r\n\r\n"` sequence.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    isStringBuilder.append(line).append("\r\n");
    if (url == null && !line.isEmpty()) {
        method = line.split("\\ ")[0];
        url = line.split("\\ ")[1];
    }
    if (line.isEmpty())
        break;
}
```

If you want to read request body `Some body`. You must add `Content-Length: LENGTH_OF_BODY` to the request header.  And server parse it, then read `LENGTH_OF_BODY` **bytes**.  In this case, you cannot use `BufferedReader`.

Comment: if (line.isEmpty())
        break;   Worked !!. Thanks